# Why isn't my basil pesto perpetuo doing well?

Tags: basil

I have a *basil pesto perpetuo* (a variegated variety of basil) I'm growing because it just looks and smells nice (not to eat).  It supposedly likes sun (it's in a pot next to a window that gets plenty of afternoon sun) and lots of water.  The soil is never-before-used potting soil.  It's gotten a lot taller since I bought it.

However, many of its leaves are just falling off.  If you breath on it hard, leaves fall off.  Why isn't it doing well?

[image]

Comment: "a lot of water" is possibly a problem. Could you give us more details? [Remember: it is a Mediterranean plant, so not used with too much water]. "plenty of afternoon sun", but I see a net in the windows, right? This reduce a lot total sun (and the plant seems to lack sun: too ling branches). Could you tell us better, when it start the "afternoon sun", and how much your windows will filter sun? [E.g. comparing open with closed windows. Modern windows may filter much light/heat, not to oeverheat the inside on summers

Comment: How long have you had the plant?

Comment: I've had it maybe a bit more than a month.

Comment: Since it's looking pretty bad now, I've moved it to our greenhouse to see if it will do better with even more sun.